# Check element exist in array and return in if condition PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array which will have 3 cases like this:

First:

```
array: [
  "QtyIn" => "0"
  "QtyOut" => "0"
]
```

Second:

```
array: [
  "QtyIn" => "0"
]
```

Third:

```
array: [
  "QtyOut" => "0"
]
```

Now I want to check if QtyIn = 0, return A. QtyOut = 0, return B. And if QtyIn and QtyOut = 0, return C. I tried with 3 if statements like this:

```
if ( isset($data['QtyIn']) && isset($data['QtyOut']) ) {
    if ( $data['QtyIn'] <= 0 && $data['QtyOut'] <= 0 ) {
        return A
    }
} 

if ( isset($data['QtyIn']) ) {
    if ( $data['QtyIn'] <= 0 ) {
        return B
    }
}

if ( isset($data['QtyOut']) ) {
    if ( $data['QtyOut'] <= 0 ) {
        return C
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to write this code more clean?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to test the conditions you say it tests.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( isset($data['QtyIn']) && isset($data['QtyOut']) ) {
    if ( $data['QtyIn'] == 0 && $data['QtyOut'] == 0 ) {
        return A;
    }else if ( $data['QtyIn'] == 0 ) {
        return B;
    }else if ( $data['QtyOut'] == 0 ) {
        return C
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first thing you do is to store the values in a temporary variable and apply `??` to set the value to some non-zero value if they are not set, then the tests become shorter...

```
function check($data)   {
    $in = $data['QtyIn'] ?? -1;
    $out = $data['QtyOut'] ?? -1;
    if ( $in == 0 && $out == 0 ) {
        return 'A';
    }
    if ( $in == 0 ) {
        return 'B';
    }
    
    if ( $out == 0 ) {
        return 'C';
    }
}
echo check(['QtyIn' => 0, 'QtyOut' => 0]);
echo check(['QtyIn' => 0]);
echo check(['QtyOut' => 0]);
```

You could shorten it using ternary expressions, but this isn't as readable (IMHO)...

```
function check($data)   {
    $in = $data['QtyIn'] ?? -1;
    $out = $data['QtyOut'] ?? -1;
    return ( $in == 0 && $out == 0 ) ? 'A' : 
        (( $in == 0 ) ? 'B' : 
                (( $out == 0 ) ? 'C' : ''));

}
```

This code also use `==` instead of `<=` 0 as @Jeto pointed out in his comment you state it must be = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner doesn't mean shorter. If you want to be cleaner, for example, this way:

```
$qtyIn = $data['QtyIn'] ?? null;
$qtyOut = $data['QtyOut'] ?? null;

if (isZeroOrLess($qtyIn) && isZeroOrLess($qtyOut)) {
    return A;
}

if (isZeroOrLess($qtyIn)) {
    return B;
}

if (isZeroOrLess($qtyOut)) {
    return C;
}

function isZeroOrLess($val = null)
{
    if ($val === null) {
        return false;
    }
    return $val <= 0;
}
```

Comment: He asked for cleaner code only, no need to create functions I guess.